Is there a way to add an extra route after a catch-all route in NextJs?
I'm using the latest version of NextJs with app router.
I have a route defined like /app/categories/[[...subCategories]].
I would like to be able to have /app/categories/[[...subCategories]]/post/[id] where post/[id] is not supposed to be in the catch-all route, so I could go on /categories/1/2/post/1 as well as /categories/1/post/2.
I don't think it's possible this way, but maybe there are more advanced ways to do so.
Does anyone know about it ?

You're right it is not possible that way, you need two separate dynamic routes:
first Catch-all route for categories


`/pages/app/categories/[[...subCategories]].js` will handle URLs like `/categories/1/2`.



an then use specific post route
By separating these routes, the catch-all won’t interfere with /post/[id] and you can still access nested categories and posts correctly.
